# How to open multiple windows in Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am working on GUI Project in Python using Tkinter,I want to open  Multiple Windows in GUI at a time each operating individually.Not one after another i.e;it should show the new form you are displaying but it should enable you to go back and use the controls in the Main Form .But I getting access to mainform only when the New Form is Closed.

How can I acheive multiple Forms ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating the root window, other windows should be instances of [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm).

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text="this is the root window").pack()
root.geometry("200x200")
for i in range(4):
    window = tk.Toplevel()
    window.geometry("200x200")

    tk.Label(window, text="this is window %s" % i).pack()

root.mainloop()
```