# How to open a Pygame window and a Tkinter window simultaneously?

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I'm making a simple game using the Pygame Module. I require a Tkinter window to be open alongside the Pygame window.

Whenever I try to open both the windows, the second window only opens after I kill the first one.

Now, the only solution I can think of, is using multi-threading. But, I'm not able to implement it.

How do I go about this?
I would really appreciate some help here.
Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a fundamental design issue in pygame that makes it unable to open a window if the process already has a window. It will also prevent other windows from opening while it is running. However, you can open as many TK windows as you like and you can embed a pygame window inside a SDL drawing frame inside a TK window.

See this answer on how to use the drawing frame: [Embedding a Pygame window into a Tkinter or WxPython frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319059/embedding-a-pygame-window-into-a-tkinter-or-wxpython-frame)

See this answer on how to create multiple windows in `tkinter`: [How to open multiple windows in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510151/how-to-open-multiple-windows-in-tkinter)

Comment: I was able get what I wanted by setting the Tkinter frame-width = 0. Now it is pretty much like a Pygame Window and I can open multiple Tkinter Windows. Really Helpful!

Comment: I just have a question, I'm printing the values of the mouse position using `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` . But now the mouse position values do not update as I move it. It worked perfectly fine before embedding the Pygame window into a Tkinter window. But now, I have to click, only then I start getting the new position values(the place where I clicked)

Comment: I'm sorry I wouldn't know. It might be that the event system does not work by default in embedded windows, and you will need to detect events in tkinter and forward them to pygame with `pygame.event.post()`